# Ruby on rails not reloading in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have recently noticed that when running a rails 5.2 project locally on my PC it doesn't auto detect changes to controllers and models. The only way I can get around it is to stop and start the server.

I have had a look around and I did find a couple of posts suggesting that I un-comment `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` in my development config and add the `gem listen`. This was mostly on forums relating to running rails on docker.

This does solve the problem(ish) - its very slow. I would still like to know why the default behaviour suddenly stopped working.

This is happening on all my rails projects on this machine which previously worked fine.

The only change I ever made to any config file was to add the devise mailer config, other than that its all defaults.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Or does anyone have any advice on solving it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which operating system are you using? Linux and OSX should work.

Comment: @nathantech333 windows 10

Comment: I started experiencing this suddenly on my Rails 6 app (no virtualization, directly on MacOS). It came out of nowhere. Everything was working fine three days ago, but now, I have to restart my server or uncomment the default EventFileUpdateChecker